# Why in Keras subclassing API, the call method is never called and as an alternative the input is passed by calling the object of this class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

When creating a model using Keras subclassing API, we write a custom model class and define a function named `call(self, x)`(mostly to write the forward pass) which expects an input. However, this method is never called and instead of passing the input to `call`, it is passed to the object of this class as `model(images)`.

How are we able to call this `model` object and pass values when we haven't implemented Python special method, `__call__` in the class

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()
```

Use tf.GradientTape to train the model:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)
```

**Shouldn't the input be passed like below:**

```
model = MyModel()
model.call(images)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually `__call__` method is implemented in the `Layer` class, which is inherited by `Network` class, which is inherited by `Model` class:

```
class Layer(module.Module):
    def __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):

class Network(base_layer.Layer):

class Model(network.Network):
```

So `MyClass` will inherit this `__call__` method.

**Additional info:**

So actually what we do is overriding the inherited `call` method, which new `call` method will be then called from the inherited `__call__` method. That is why we don't need to do a `model.call()`.
So when we call our model instance, it's inherited `__call__` method will be executed automatically, which calls our own `call` method.

Comment: I see that the `call` method is called from `__call__ `. But `def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):` is not an abstract method then how are we able to implement `def call` in our custom class

Comment: @Atul see my answer's additional info section with my updated answer.

Comment: Just for reference, in case someone is looking for, we can find all details of layer class https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#call, including source code

Answer (score 3):

Occam's razor says that the `__call__` method is implemented in the `Model` class, so your subclass will inherit this method, which is why the call works. The `__call__` in the `Model` class just forwards parameters to your `call` method and does some bookkeeping.